# Create a search for my HTML and CSS site that runs without an internet connection or database?

Tags: html, php, mysql, search, meta-tags

I have a website that I have written out in plain old HTML and CSS, and want to integrate a search function into it. However, the site is meant to be run offline, from host machines in their local web browsers (i.e. without an internet connection).

I realize that I could easily integrate a search using a mySQL database, though that would require everyone to have a mySQL database running on their computer with the proper data. I was wondering if it would be possible to integrate a search box that wouldn't need to connect to a database (or at least one that didn't require an AMP stack running on each user's local machine).

I have searched around and haven't been able to find a solution to a similar problem. The search doesn't have to be simple, just something that would be able to present the titles of HTML pages in a list (I don't need the content of each HTML document to be searched, just the titles of each page). I was thinking there might be some way to return the titles and descriptions of each page for the search either using each page's `<meta>` tags, or by having a plain text document at the site root with a listing of all of the pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to automatically search through all the HTML files. However, assuming your pages are generated in some way for the user to download, you could also generate a Javascript file with an array of pages/keywords.

For example it could generate some JSON object like `var site_index = [ {page:"hello.html",keywords:"hello,world,etc"}, ... ];`

Then a function to take an input from a form and find matching pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sitemap/index XML file including the titles (and perhaps some keywords) for use in search
2. Apply an [XSL template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) on the sitemap/index XML file which displays a search form
3. Create a Javascript which responds to search form input with an [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) to filter/sort the sitemap/index XML file

Answer (score 0):

This would work, as long as the machines could have access to a local copy of the necessary php file.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

It's pretty simple to implement, also it perfectly matches you criteria

> "just something that would be able to present the titles of HTML pages
>   in a list (I don't need the content of each HTML document to be
>   searched, just the titles of each page)."